# Pandas Better Way To Trim Data

Tags: python, database, pandas

I currently have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4,5,6,7], 'BBB' : [100,100,30,40],'CCC' : [100,100,30,-50]})
```

I also have the data frame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4], 'BBB' : [100]})
```

where I define

```
relevantColumns=['AAA','BBB']
```

which is just a list of the columns that df1.

I want to find the index for which df1 appears in df.  I currently have something that looks like this,

```
trueNFalses=(df==df1)[columnsToSort] #This generates a boolean dataframe

#Now I want to find the row with two trues in it, this is the row where df1 appears.

numTrues=trueNFalses.sum(axis=1)

#Now I look through numTrues and find the index of every values of 2,  
#because that is where there were two trues.

indices=numTrues[numTrues==len(columnsToSort)].axes
```

So I do what feels like a very round about computation just to get the indices where df has has the columns that df1 has.  I feel silly doing all of this because I'm almost certain there must be a better way to do this in pandas.  My technique also has a few downsides I would love to fix but do not know how. For example I really need indices to be a dataframe, but with my code it is a list of dtype object, which is awkward for future processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then indexes values are in column `index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4,5,6,7], 
                   'BBB' : [100,100,30,40],
                   'CCC' : [100,100,30,-50]}, index=[2,3,4,5])

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4], 'BBB' : [100]}, index=[8])

relevantColumns=['AAA','BBB']

print df
   AAA  BBB  CCC
2    4  100  100
3    5  100  100
4    6   30   30
5    7   40  -50

print df1
   AAA  BBB
8    4  100

print pd.merge(df.reset_index(), df1, on=relevantColumns, how='right')
   index  AAA  BBB  CCC
0      2    4  100  100

print pd.merge(df.reset_index(), df1, on=relevantColumns, how='right')['index']
0    2
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was lookin for!!